# Can't extract first column Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series object w/ following shape

```
             H      AB     HBP     SF    G   2B   3B   HR    BAVG  
playerID                                                                                         
ruthba01   2873   8398   43.0    0.0  2503  506  136  714  0.342105  
willite01  2654   7706   39.0   20.0  2292  525   71  521  0.344407  
gehrilo01  2721   8001   45.0    0.0  2164  534  163  493  0.340082  
hornsro01  2930   8173   48.0    0.0  2259  541  169  301  0.358497
```

I am trying to extract the first column(playerIDs) and convert it to a list. However, list = df['playerID'] gives KeyError, iLoc[0] will return the H column. FYI its a series object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the playerID in index

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Then you can call your `.iloc` and `df['playerID']`

---

Or we do not need reset

```
l = df.index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the index you just need `df.index` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the first column might be set to an index. To turn it to a list you will use `df.index.tolist()`